# Do Javascript functionality break when html has some unclosed tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an existing asp.net web application which is there from like 10 years. So far it was running in compatibility mode to IE5. Now it has to be converted to IE11 Edge compatible. Suddenly, below typical JavaScript and J-Query tag started to fail:

`document.getElementById('id of element')`. and `$('#id of element')`

I checked that the div is present on page and view source. While going through the html generated in View Source, I noticed that there were numerous unclosed tags.

So my question is will unclosed HTML tags affect working of JavaScript? What could be other reasons for failing above statement? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the html surrounding the javascript?

Comment: Javascript works with the DOM. When the page is being parsed and rendered the browser will automatically close any unclosed tags, when creating the DOM structure. So, no, it should not affect your Javascript. **Edit:** Okay, I did not know of this until now but IE seems to have problems with it. Go figure.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen No, you are correct. IE just used different rules to load the DOM from the invalid HTML.

Comment: 'View Source' will show the *actual/plain HTML*. View the DOM to see the *effective document*, after parsing. The DOM cannot have unclosed/unbalanced tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty standard for IE to throw a hissy fit when you don't close your HTML tags and try to access them with JavaScript.  There's a decent article on it here: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/close_your_tags

Comment: If it's in the DOM it is accessible via JS. Therefor the 'hissy fit' is merely that the HTML is not being created as expected in the DOM (HTML5 makes the handling rules a bit more formalized AFAIK, but invalid HTML is still invalid); and has nothing specifically to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unclosed HTML tags can affect working of JavaScript if you are testing it in IE.